# Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory'

Tags: spring, jackson-databind

I am running into below error not sure what is the issue. I have below jackson dependency and spring on 5.2.22.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>


 Exception Details:
      Location:
        com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
      Reason:
        Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
      Current Frame:
        bci: @7
        flags: { }
        locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
        stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
      Bytecode:
        0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0
```

Comment: some how it was referencing weblogic's jackson jars at times. so I had to force it to use application jars - <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>